# Cannot send mail to addresses of specific domain through Rails' ActionMailer in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

When I try to send a mail through ActionMailer from Rails production console to a specific domain, then the mail won't be send without error message:

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: "me@myhost.com", to: "gawlista.mathias@specific_domain.com", subject: "Test", body: "Dummy").deliver_now
```

When I change the address to me@gmail.com it works.
I also can send mail from Ubuntu command line to any address:

```
mail -s "Test" gawlista.mathias@specific_domain.com
```

The only production environment setting regarding mail is:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myhost.com' }
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0p0 in production.
It has been working for a long time and since February 26th it's broken.

Any suggestion how to solve that or debugging tips?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I use the mailgun API, figured out that my e-mail address got blocked by it and enabled the e-mail address again.